# How to package a custom domain name for Experience (Community)

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, custom-domain, experience-bundle

I have an experience that is packaged in an unlocked package.   In production, we are using a custom domain, but we are not using that in the sandboxes.  Whenever we deploy the package to production, it wipes out the custom domain and we have to reset it.  Is there a way for me to package the custom domain so that we don't do this (but so that the sandboxes also still work?)

Comment: I suspect you cannot but will be interested to see what others have to say.